# Zend_Db and Date Based Queries

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm using Zend_Db to query a table.  I have some `WHERE` clauses that need to be dates and it's not clear (at first glance) how to do this "the right way". Does Zend_Db provide an abstraction so I don't need to concern myself with how the backend (Oracle, MySQL, etc.) expects its dates?  Or do I need to format things in the way my backend expects them.

I'm trying the following with an Oracle based database (PO_DATE is a timestamp field)

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();               
$select = $table->select()->where('1 = ?', 1);      
$select->where('PO_DATE = ?', '2009-12-02');
```

and I get the following exception

```
  <b>Message:</b> 1843 ORA-01843: not a valid month SELECT "TABLE_NAME".* FROM "SYSTEM"."TABLE_NAME" WHERE (1 = 1) AND (PO_DATE = *'2009-12-02')  </p>
```

I realize I could do something like this

```
$date = new Zend_Db_Expr(
"to_date('2009-12-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"
);
$select->where('PO_DATE = ?', $date);
```

but that ties me to Oracle's date based Expressions, which partially defeats the purpose of using a SQL abstraction layer.

Is there a generic way to do date queries independent of the back-end implementation with Zend_Db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely like such a capability, however, I haven't found any in the Zend Framework.  This [issue](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-1978) in their tracker also makes me pretty confident its not in there yet.

Comment: THanks for saving me a night of searching for something that isn't there :)

Comment: See also http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8538 which looks like it will be implemented

Answer (score 1):

A lot of DB vendors (including Oracle) will support this format:

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();                           
$select = $table->select()->where('1 = ?', 1);          
$select->where('PO_DATE = ?', '02-Dec-2009');
```

So I tend to do that until they have better support for date/string conversion in Zend_Db

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact I don't see any kind of contract in

```
abstract class Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
```

that implies "convert dates into a universal format" functionality, I assume the answer to my question is no, but with a large framework one never knows, and it seems like the kind of thing ripe for an abstraction.